# Use NFC reader on Raspberry Pi to remotely skip Gnome lock screen

Tags: gnome, remote

I'm not sure how to well summarise what I want to do, hear me out.

I want to have a Raspberry Pi with an NFC tag reader. Once the user taps their tag, the Pi would check if that user has permissions and... yeah, that's my question. My goal is to have my desktop PC running Ubuntu 20.04 (Gnome) to unlock (as if, the screen is locked, I sit down and type my password -- instead of that, I want to just tap the NFC tag).

But that's the problem: **I want the NFC tag reader to be plugged into my Pi, not into the PC I want to unlock.** Is it possible to configure Gnome to unlock the lock screen? If yes, then I could make an app that listens for HTTP requests, or do something similar to receive info that a correct tag has been scanned.

I know this would be unsecure, but I'm only making it as a proof-of-concept prototype.

---

tl;dr: Is there any way to skip Gnome lock screen remotely?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, if you have systemd (which you do on Ubuntu 20.04):

```
  loginctl unlock-sessions
```

will unlock all sessions but needs to be executed by `root` or asks for root password. Note the plural session**s**, as opposed to

```
  loginctl unlock-session <ID>
```

which is also possible to do as the user, but you will have to pick the right ID from `loginctl list-sessions` and make a little script of it. As you are yourself in that case, no password is needed. Actually it should always be `ID=1` on a single-user desktop system. But I am not 100% certain here.

Security-wise it is then not so bad, as all you need would be a key-based ssh login to run the command/script.

Comment: Exactly what I wanted, thank you!